# Paypal IPN: certificate verify failed

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

Since yesterday I'm unable to receive paypal ipn notifications. I've check the log file and the error is:

```
[24-Mar-2015 13:48:44] cURL error: [60] SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php-paypal-error: 14077410:SSL routines:SSL23\_GET\_SERVER\_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926940/php-paypal-error-14077410ssl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-hands)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the certificate wasn't valid anymore.

I followed the code comments on the [paypal ipn listener sample](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/) and downloaded a new certificate from  http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html (**HTTPS from github: ca-bundle.crt**) and replaced the old one. Problem solved.

I hope it helps others.

Comment: @KimL Always glad to help:)  Please consider voting for it, tks!

Comment: Where can I find the old one to replace?

Comment: @ZetaAl, The path to the old cert should be somewhere on your curl code block.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I already find out that, but I have some problems implementing it.. I started a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709289/paypal-using-ipn-and-ssl

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by updating root certificates in Ubuntu by running sudo update-ca-certificates