# PayPal IPN Notifications: SSL Certificate Verify Failed

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

In the last week or so I have not received any PayPal IPN notifications. The error I am getting in the log file is:

```
[03-Apr-2015 00:16:00] cURL error: [60] SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Steps I have taken:

1. I saw a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235389/paypal-ipn-certificate-verify-failed) on this and downloaded the cacert.pem file.
2. I updated the certificate name in my ipn php file.
3. I checked the permissions on the new certificate and the associated folders to ensure they are all set to both read and execute.
4. I have already set the following: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);`

I test again using the IPN simulator and continue to get the same error. Any thoughts on what else may be needed here?

Here is the ipn listener code:

```
<?php

class IpnListener {

    public $use_curl = true;     
    public $force_ssl_v3 = true;     
    public $follow_location = false;     
    public $use_ssl = true;      
    public $use_sandbox = true; 
    public $timeout = 30;       

    private $post_data = array();
    private $post_uri = '';     
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';

    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'www.sandbox.paypal.com';

    protected function curlPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        } else {
            $uri = 'http://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 
                    dirname(__FILE__)."/cert/cacert.pem");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);

        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
    }

    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'ssl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
            $port = '443';
            $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $uri = $this->getPaypalHost(); // no "http://" in call to fsockopen()
            $port = '80';
            $this->post_uri = 'http://'.$uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }

        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

        if (!$fp) { 
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        } 

        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ".$this->getPaypalHost()."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($fp)) { 
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024); 
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
            }
        } 

        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function getPaypalHost() {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) return self::SANDBOX_HOST;
        else return self::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }

    public function getPostUri() {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }

    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }

    public function getResponseStatus() {
        return $this->response_status;
    }

    public function getTextReport() {

        $r = '';

        // date and POST url
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) $r .= " (curl)\n";
        else $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";

        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";

        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";

        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";

        return $r;
    }

    public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

        $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if ($post_data === null) { 
            // use raw POST data 
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $this->post_data = $_POST;
                $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
            }
        } else { 
            // use provided data array
            $this->post_data = $post_data;

            foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
                $encoded_data .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
            }
        }

        if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data); 
        else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data);

        if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
        }

        if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
            return true;
        } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
        }
    }

    public function requirePostMethod() {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your IPN script removing all the sensitive information ? It should be related to the certificate only as I was able to resolve it by replacing the certificate .

Comment: Same works fine for me . Did you make sure that in the .pem certifcate is the latest one in your directory . It must  the below line somewhere "VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5". Can you open your pem in text editor and see for this line? or just download the certificate as mentioned in the above post and replace it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by reverting back to my old certificate file and pasting the "VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5" certificate section into it (from cacert.pem). This feels like a bit of a hack, but I just couldn't get it to work when referencing cacert.pem.

I didn't feel comfortable security-wise setting verify peer to false.

Thankyou to all for ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to remove the CURLOPT_CAINFO option and instead set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false.  Here is an example:

```
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($request, array
(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array('cmd'=>'_notify_validate') + $_POST),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
));
```

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that a + sign in PHP does an `array_merge()` like that, but only if one appends an `array()` statement to an array variable. If one tries to do like `$array1 + $array2`, they'll only get `$array1`.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. It seems old ssl libraries have issues with fresh cacert.pem. Resolved by using "an older ca-bundle from github" (the last CA bundle converted from before RSA-1024 removal):
https://github.com/bagder/ca-bundle/blob/e9175fec5d0c4d42de24ed6d84a06d504d5e5a09/ca-bundle.crt