# Paypal IPN certificate Invalid

Tags: ssl, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been facing this issue with the Paypal IPN since last couple of days 
I had this similar problem before which got resolved with the help of the post [Paypal IPN: certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235389/paypal-ipn-certificate-verify-failed)

```
cURL error: [60] SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

it worked fine till couple of days back and suddenly started breaking the flow

I tried by setting the curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1); but it didnt helped

Any ideas what could be the possible cause ?

Comment: Refer to link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235389/paypal-ipn-certificate-verify-failed

Comment: @Eshan : Thanks for replying but like I said in the question i followed that link as well I updated the cert but it didn't worked