# Paypal using IPN and SSL

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

I am trying to implement Paypal with IPN (Instant Payment Notification). 
But as a lot of people here I get this error: "Error SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086: SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

My page doesn't have an SSL certificate, it is only http.
**So my first question is: Do I need a SSL certificate? Because I read somewhere that it is not necessary.**

I tried downloading SSL bundle file from here: [Bundle file](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) and replacing them in php.ini and also in my file.

This is the code:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); // change to [...]sandbox.paypal[...] when using sandbox to test
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,'C:\xampp\htdocs\page\cacert.pem');
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,'C:\xampp\htdocs\page\ca-bundle.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
```

**Is there a way to ignore this error or some other workaround?**

Comment: do you have a Certification Authority ?

Comment: No? As I understand how it works, when I request a SSL certificate, the CA issues it..so I goes I do not have a CA..

Comment: You do not need an SSL to use IPN.

Comment: Then I don't understand what is causing this problem.